# Upgrading WildFly From 8 to 14 java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02275: such a referential constraint already exists in the table

Tags: java, hibernate, wildfly

My project uses Hibernate as JPA provider and I'm upgrading my WildFly version from 8.2.1.Final release to 14.0.1.Final release. The project runs on WildFly 8.x version with no problem. When I don't any change and run project on WildFly 14.x version, I'm getting this warning message:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02275: such a referential constraint already exists in the table
```

I checked and saw that WildFly 8.x contains and uses Hibernate 4.3.7 releases. WildFly 14.x contains and uses Hibernate 5.3.6.

My project uses Hibernate 4.3.5. and I'm calling hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto property with update value in persistence.xml. I think that Hibernate shouldn't try to create any thing because there is no change on database entities.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

hbm2ddl.auto property and it's value:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
```

Is there any change in Hibernate from 4.3.7 to 5.3.6 to get this warning message? How can I handle this warning messages?

Comment: Can you upgrade Hibernate and try again? However, it's probably not your solution.

Comment: @achAmháin, yes. I upgraded Hibernate version to 5.3.7 and run again but again I got warning message.

Comment: what warning message?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Warning message is this : 
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02275: such a referential constraint already exists in the table

Comment: have you had a look at the SQL hibernate is creating?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, Sorry, I forgot one point to add question and I added. 'm calling hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto property with "update" value in persistence.xml. I think that Hibernate shouldn't try to create any thing because there is no change on database entities.

Comment: and which referential constraint is hibernate trying to create?

Comment: I used OneToOne and JoinColumn notations to create foreign keys between tables. Such as I have User and computer entity and computer has a user_id as a foreign key. When I start the project on servers, I'm getting this warning messages from many tables. On the other hand, I found a link that's about this problem. Do you think that this is not important topic according to this link: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10574